# MatProgressBar - How to avoid staggering animation when update rate is high

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular material [MatProgressBar](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview) component.

I'm facing a problem with `determinate` mode. when the update interval for the `value` is lower than 250msec i'm getting animation staggers.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuha5f?file=app/progress-bar-determinate-example.ts)

**Component.ts**

```
export class ProgressBarDeterminateExample implements OnInit {
  progressA = 0;
  progressB = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    const VALID_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MSEC = 250;
    const INVALID_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MSEC = 100;

    interval(VALID_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MSEC).subscribe(val => this.progressA = val)
    interval(INVALID_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MSEC).subscribe(val => this.progressB = val)
  }
}
```

**Component.HTML**

```
<!-- at 250sec update rate - all valid -->
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progressA"></mat-progress-bar>

<!-- under 250sec update rate - staggering animation -->
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progressB" color="warn"></mat-progress-bar>
```

I am well aware the main issue lies somewhere around the `transition-duration` of the bar element but can't quite put my finger where exactly.

Losing events is not an option so rxjs's `throttleTime(250)` or so won't solve it.

**EDIT:**
I could not find a CSS way to fully work this issue out, so went with @observingstream's suggestion to separate event handling logic.

so instead of:

```
interval.subscribe(v => // event handling)
```

I separated logic to two handlers:

```
interval(INVALID_UPDATE_RATE_IN_MSEC)
  .pipe(
    // business logic with event
    tap(val => console.log(val) ),
    // throttle for animation
    throttleTime(250),
    // animation logic
    tap(val => this.progressB++)
  )
  .subscribe()
```

[Solution Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuha5f-bmemgy?file=app/progress-bar-determinate-example.ts)

Comment: Why do you need all of the events to just show the progress? I would agree that you don't want to lose the progress events for other processes, but for the progress bar, you just need to show the bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the css for the animation by using `:host ::ng-deep` to change which transition. If you change it to the following, it appears to work.

```
:host ::ng-deep {
  .updating-animation.mat-progress-bar .mat-progress-bar-fill {
    transition: transform 100ms linear;
  }
}
```

That being said, if you have that many updates coming in, it would be good to throttle them in some way and fill the gap with the animation.

See https://stackblitz.com/angular/yojaylpekgn?file=app%2Fprogress-bar-configurable-example.ts

Comment: I could not find a way for those CSS rules to fix the animation. I did however went with your suggestion of keeping events to the progress bar separate from the logic, so for future readers: `interval().pipe(tap().throttleTime().tap()).subscribe()` [seperation of logics stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuha5f-bmemgy?file=app/progress-bar-determinate-example.ts)

Comment: I am glad that you got it working. On a side note, I wanted to clarify that if you share your observable, you can have one stream that deals with the progress and another that does the business logic. I have made a simple example of this here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuha5f-gekjop?file=app/progress-bar-determinate-example.ts)